# Database design query regarding column that can have multiple values

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I have a table named Forum which has following columns:

1. stu_id  -> foreign key
2. query
3. query_date
4. solution
5. query_title

Now i am confused on how to implement this table in mysql. All the columns in the table will have single value at a time except the solution column , as we know that for a single query there can be multiple solutions. So should i create a one more table say solution_table.

Now the Tables will be:

Forum

1. stu_id  -> foreign key
2. query
3. query_date
4. solution_id
5. query_title

Solution_table

1. solution_id
2. solution_ans

IS this correct?Or is there any other method to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be the correct way to implement this. If the solution_ans are going to be a finite list of solutions then that is all that you would need in the Solution_table. If the answers are going to be dynamic, I would think about having a foreign key in the solution_table that links to the stu_id. This way when you are looking at the data you can easily connect each answer to the forum post/question

I would look into normalization of databases to understand why this is a good solution for this particular problem.